# How to make my loop work properly to produce correct output?

Tags: java

```
        public class p6
        {

            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                System.out.println("celsius \t Fahrenheit \t | Fahrenheit \t\t Celsius");

                for (double i = 31; i <= 40; i++) {

        System.out.printf(i + "\t\t" + "\t" + "%.2f", +celsiusToFahrenheit(i));
        System.out.println("");
    }


    for (j = 30; j <= 120; j++) {

        System.out.printf("\t\t\t\t" +j + "\t\t\t\t" + "%.2f",+fahrenheitToCelsius(j));
        System.out.println("");
    }
                }
            }

            // • Converts a Celsius value to Fahrenheit
           // • Converts a Celsius value to Fahrenheit
            public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius)
            {
                return (9.0 / 5) * celsius + 32;
            }

            // Converts a Fahrenheit value to Celsius
            public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit)
            {
                return (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
            }
        }
```

This is the output, I am getting but I need it to be all in order.

```
celsius      Fahrenheit      | Fahrenheit        Celsius
31.0            87.80
32.0            89.60
33.0            91.40
34.0            93.20
35.0            95.00
36.0            96.80
37.0            98.60
38.0            100.40
39.0            102.20
40.0            104.00
                30.0                -1.11
                31.0                -0.56
                32.0                0.00
                33.0                0.56
                34.0                1.11
                35.0                1.67
                36.0                2.22
                37.0                2.78
                38.0                3.33
                39.0                3.89
                40.0                4.44
                41.0                5.00
                42.0                5.56
                43.0                6.11
                44.0                6.67
                45.0                7.22
                46.0                7.78
                47.0                8.33
                48.0                8.89
                49.0                9.44
                50.0                10.00
                51.0                10.56
                52.0                11.11
                53.0                11.67
                54.0                12.22
                55.0                12.78
                56.0                13.33
                57.0                13.89
                58.0                14.44
                59.0                15.00
                60.0                15.56
                61.0                16.11
                62.0                16.67
                63.0                17.22
                64.0                17.78
                65.0                18.33
                66.0                18.89
                67.0                19.44
                68.0                20.00
                69.0                20.56
                70.0                21.11
                71.0                21.67
                72.0                22.22
                73.0                22.78
                74.0                23.33
                75.0                23.89
                76.0                24.44
                77.0                25.00
                78.0                25.56
                79.0                26.11
                80.0                26.67
                81.0                27.22
                82.0                27.78
                83.0                28.33
                84.0                28.89
                85.0                29.44
                86.0                30.00
                87.0                30.56
                88.0                31.11
                89.0                31.67
                90.0                32.22
                91.0                32.78
                92.0                33.33
                93.0                33.89
                94.0                34.44
                95.0                35.00
                96.0                35.56
                97.0                36.11
                98.0                36.67
                99.0                37.22
                100.0               37.78
                101.0               38.33
                102.0               38.89
                103.0               39.44
                104.0               40.00
                105.0               40.56
                106.0               41.11
                107.0               41.67
                108.0               42.22
                109.0               42.78
                110.0               43.33
                111.0               43.89
                112.0               44.44
                113.0               45.00
                114.0               45.56
                115.0               46.11
                116.0               46.67
                117.0               47.22
                118.0               47.78
                119.0               48.33
                120.0               48.89
```

I need to get the output in a table, but the problem i am having right now is that the the numbers are being repeated so many times each. The loop does stop, what it is not I need to get. If i used a different loop it works fine but I need to the the output in two different columns.

I am converting celsius to fahrenheit, so in one column should display celsius and another the fahrenheit.

```
    Then I am convering F to C, so in another column I need to display F and another the C.
    I need to get one column with celsius and another column with 

    The four columns have to be next to each other.
```

Comment: First, please fix your code indentation, remove the commented out code, remove the excessive blank lines (not all of them - but there's no need to have the amount you've got here) and then tell us what you've got vs what you want it to do. It's not at *all* clear what the expected output should be at the moment.

Comment: Any reason you are making a loop within a loop?

Comment: I think you want to break line in the first loop instead of the second one. @gtgaxiola I think he does that because the output to look like a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need a single loop, not a nested loop.

Second of all, in order for each F to C conversion to have a corresponding C to F conversion in the same row, `i` and `j` must have the same number of values.

Here's a possible way to do it :

```
    double j = 30;
    for (double i = 31; i <= 40; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "\t\t" + "\t" +celsiusToFahrenheit(i)+"\t\t\t" +j + "\t\t\t\t"+fahrenheitToCelsius(j));
        System.out.println("");
        j+=10; // since i has 10 values (31 to 40), j must increment by 10 in each 
               // iteration in order for it to have 10 values between 30 and 120
    }
```

The output:

```
celsius      Fahrenheit      | Fahrenheit        Celsius
31.0            87.80000000000001           30.0                -1.1111111111111112
32.0            89.6            40.0                4.444444444444445
33.0            91.4            50.0                10.0
34.0            93.2            60.0                15.555555555555557
35.0            95.0            70.0                21.11111111111111
36.0            96.8            80.0                26.666666666666668
37.0            98.60000000000001           90.0                32.22222222222222
38.0            100.4           100.0               37.77777777777778
39.0            102.2           110.0               43.333333333333336
40.0            104.0           120.0               48.88888888888889
```

It still requires a minor fix in the formatting, but it's very close to what you wanted.

Better formatting:

```
System.out.println("celsius \tFahrenheit\t | \tFahrenheit \t\tCelsius");
double j = 30;
for (double i = 31; i <= 40; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f\t\t%.2f\t\t\t%.2f\t\t\t%.2f", i, celsiusToFahrenheit(i),j,fahrenheitToCelsius(j));
    System.out.println("");
    j+=10; // since i has 10 values (31 to 40), j must increment by 10 in each 
           // iteration in order for it to have 10 values between 30 and 120
}
```

Output:

```
celsius     Fahrenheit   |  Fahrenheit      Celsius
31.00       87.80           30.00           -1.11
32.00       89.60           40.00           4.44
33.00       91.40           50.00           10.00
34.00       93.20           60.00           15.56
35.00       95.00           70.00           21.11
36.00       96.80           80.00           26.67
37.00       98.60           90.00           32.22
38.00       100.40          100.00          37.78
39.00       102.20          110.00          43.33
40.00       104.00          120.00          48.89
```

Comment: why not just use `i` for both conversions, and not use `j`?

Comment: @SamIam That all depends on the values the OP wants to convert in each direction. If the OP wants to convert from C to F values between 31 and 40, but wants to convert from F to C values between 30 and 120, you either need two variables, or you need to calculate j as a function of i.

Comment: Yes I will figure out about fixing the decimals. How will I be able to go instead from 31 to 40 but instead 40 to 31 and 120 to 40? Eran

Comment: @user3269660 If you want to reverse the order, initialize i to 40, j to 120, change i++ to i--, j+=10 to j-=10 and i<=40 to i>=31.